# Rmd file which sources an R script which sources another R script

Tags: r, r-package, organization, code-organization, r-devtools

To make my code modular, I wrote a R script for plotting data, which invokes an R script to prepare the data (to be plotted):

The `document.Rmd` file contains a line `source('./R/customPlot.R')` and this script in turns contains a line `source('./prepareData.R')`.

Running the `document.Rmd` gives me an error message that `./prepareData.R` was not found, which could easily be fixed by changing the line in the script `customPlot.R` to `source('./R/prepareData.R`).

In this case, however, I could no longer just run `customPlot.R` on it's own to visually check its output.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
project/
  Rmd/
    document.Rmd   # calls source('./R/customPlot.R')
  R/
    customPlot.R   # calls source('./prepareData.R')
    prepareData.R
```

By searching the web, I learned that generating a package of my code might be a possible solution. Although my project is a bit larger, I wanted to ask whether it's worth the overhead. After all, the majority of files in my project are data and actually few of them are code.

Comment: R has no good built-in solution for this. Consider using a modern module system, via [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box).

Answer (score 1):

Heh, interesting...

The solution might be with `here::here()` function, like:

```
project/
  Rmd/
    document.Rmd  
      #'
      source(file = "../R/1.R")
      #'
  R/
    customPlot.R
      #' 
      source(file =  paste0(here::here(), "/R/prepareData.R"))
      #'
    prepareData.R
```

Comment: Thanks, this is already helpful. Best would of course be a solution without additional dependencies.

Comment: Then move .Rmd to `project` folder, out of `Rmd` subfolder. The thing is, RStudio projects uses their `project` folder as main/base folder...

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, although it would make the code organization a bit less obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the user runs the code from the working directory `project/`, i.e. it’s not robust.